# How to convert a string to camelcase in Google Spreadsheet formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, camelcasing

Trying to create a formula to turn a string of words separated by spaces into camelcase

Comment: Just "=PROPER(<cell>)" should work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
=JOIN("",ArrayFormula(UPPER(LEFT(SPLIT(A3," ")))&LOWER(MID(SPLIT(A3," "),2,500))))
```

or to be more precise:

```
=JOIN("",ArrayFormula(UPPER(LEFT(SPLIT(A3," ")))&LOWER(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A3," "),".(.*)"))))
```

Answer (score 27):

Much smaller version:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(TRIM(A1))," ","")
```

We just use `PROPER` to upper case and `TRIM` and `SUBSTITUTE` to remove spaces.

If we want lowerCamelCase,

By just `REPLACE`ing the first character with lower case, We have:

```
=REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(TRIM(A1))," ",),1,1,LEFT(LOWER(TRIM(A1))))
```

Using REGEX:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(PROPER(A1),"\s*",),"^(\w)",LEFT(LOWER(TRIM(A1))))

=LOWER(LEFT(TRIM(A1)))&REGEXREPLACE(PROPER(TRIM(A1)),"(\w|\s)(\w*)","$2")
```

Comment: My understanding is that this will look more like `SomeWordsHere` instead of `someWordsHere`. Correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: @Ryan,Yes. I thought that was the original Ⓠ. If you want lower camel casing, it's not that hard from here: `=REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(TRIM(A3))," ",""), 1,1,LOWER(LEFT(TRIM(A3))))` This will give `someWordsHere` lowerCamelCase

Comment: Without the `TRIM` failsafes this formula would look much smaller.

Answer (score 4):

To do this the following formula works (where `A3` is the cell)

**tl;dr**:

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND(" ",A3)), CONCAT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(LOWER(A3), FIND(" ", A3)), " ", ""), SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(A3, LEFT(A3, FIND(" ", A3)), "")), " ", "")), LOWER(A3))
```

---

Annotated:

```
=IF(                               // if a single word
    IFERROR(                       // test if NOT an error
        FIND(                      // looking for a space
            " ",
            A3
        )
    ),
    CONCAT(                        // concat the first word with the rest
        SUBSTITUTE(                // remove the space
            LEFT(                  // left of the find
                LOWER(             // lowercase the string
                    A3
                ),
                FIND(              // find the space in the string
                    " ",
                    A3
                )
            ),
            " ",
            ""
        ),
        SUBSTITUTE(                // remove spaces
            PROPER(                // convert string to capitals
                SUBSTITUTE(        // remove first word
                    A3,
                    LEFT(          // left of the find
                        A3,
                        FIND(      // find first space
                            " ",
                            A3
                        )
                    ),
                    ""
                )
            ),
            " ",
            ""
        )
    ),
    LOWER(                      // lowercase rest of the word
        A3
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking cue from all answers, sharing what I did as no one has mentioned it in the following exact way (transformation e.g. `created_at => createdAt`)

```
=REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(A5), "_", ""), 1, 1, LOWER(LEFT(A5, 1)))
```

The above formula is

- Easy => uses simple to understand popular functions
- Correct => works on empty cells too
- Efficient => parses the "whole" string only ONCE

Most of the work is done using PROPER function except the last part to replace first character with its lowercase version

Comment: Not sure how it is different from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46358267)