# lower CamelCase in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, camelcasing

I was wondering if anyone had advice for creating a function that transformed text_with_spaces into lower camel case like textWithSpaces

[I've found a related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43399328/how-to-convert-a-string-to-camelcase-in-google-spreadsheet-formula), that helps with regular camel case, but I'm not sure how to bring it to lower CamelCase

Comment: Provide a couple more sample data in a sample sheet. Are the words delimited by "_" or spaces?

Comment: And what have you tried so far adapting that formula?

Answer (score 1):

ASSUMING It's just text with spaces,

Here's another answer using `REPLACE` and `SUBSTITUTE`:

```
=REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(TRIM(A1))," ",""),1,1,LEFT(LOWER(TRIM(A1))))
```

Using REGEX:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(PROPER(A1),"\s*",""),"^(\w)",LEFT(LOWER(TRIM(A1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If to go from `text_with_spaces` to `textWithSpaces` try:

```
=left(A1)&mid(join("",arrayformula(proper(mid(split(A1,"_"),1,len(A1))))),2,len(A1))
```

If to go from `text with spaces` to `textWithSpaces` try:

```
=left(A1)&mid(join("",arrayformula(proper(mid(split(A1," "),1,len(A1))))),2,len(A1))
```

[LEFT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079)
[MID](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094129)
[JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077)
[PROPER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094133)
[SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
[LEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081)